# Matching split string to pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

Currently I'm splitting the titles of cars for sales
 using the split() function. I'm then itterating through a csv file, read by pandas to look for matching strings.
Here is my current script:

`title = 'ABARTH Abarth 500 124 1.4l 22,200miles UK'
keywords = title.split()`

```
for word in keywords:
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    makes = row[1]
    models = row[3]

    if word in makes:
        print('Found: ' + word + ' as a match with ' + makes + ' in pd data set.')

        pass
    else:
        print('no')

    if word in models:
        print('Found: ' + word + ' as a match with ' + models + ' in pd data set.')
        pass
```

Once I successfully match the 'make' how can I match the appropriate 'model'?

Comment: what isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) will help to you to find the matching strings, then do need to apply filter on the data frame using [DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html). You just need to repeat these 2 functions for make & model as you need. Since the data you provided wasn't sufficient, I created a sample data and here is the code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
from io import StringIO

words = ['amc', 'buick','volkswagen']
Models = "|".join(map(re.escape, words))

words = ['European','American']
Origins = "|".join(map(re.escape, words))

TESTDATA=StringIO("""
Model,MPG,Cylinders,Engine Disp,Horsepower,Weight,Accelerate,Year,Origin
amc ambassador dpl,15.0,8,390,190,3850,8.5,70,American
amc gremlin,21.0,6,199,90,2648,15.0,70,American
amc hornet,18.0,6,199,97,2774,15.5,70,American
amc rebel sst,16.0,8,304,150,3433,12.0,70,American
buick estate wagon (sw),14.0,8,455,225,3086,10.0,70,American
buick skylark 320,15.0,8,350,165,3693,11.5,70,American
chevrolet chevelle malibu,18.0,8,307,130,3504,12.0,70,American
chevrolet impala,14.0,8,454,220,4354,9.0,70,American
volkswagen 1131 deluxe sedan,26.0,4,97,46,1835,20.5,70,European
fiat 124b,30.0,4,88,76,2065,14.5,71,European
opel 1900,28.0,4,116,90,2123,14.0,71,European
peugeot 304,30.0,4,79,70,2074,19.5,71,European
volkswagen model 111,27.0,4,97,60,1834,19.0,71,European   """)

df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=",")

df=df.loc[df.Model.str.contains(Models)]
df=df.loc[df.Origin.str.contains(Origins)]
print (df)
```

Output

```
                         Model   MPG  Cylinders  Engine Disp  Horsepower    Weight  Accelerate  Year       Origin  
0             amc ambassador dpl  15.0          8          390         190    3850         8.5    70     American   
1                    amc gremlin  21.0          6          199          90    2648        15.0    70     American   
2                     amc hornet  18.0          6          199          97    2774        15.5    70     American   
3                  amc rebel sst  16.0          8          304         150    3433        12.0    70     American   
4        buick estate wagon (sw)  14.0          8          455         225    3086        10.0    70     American   
5              buick skylark 320  15.0          8          350         165    3693        11.5    70     American   
8   volkswagen 1131 deluxe sedan  26.0          4           97          46    1835        20.5    70     European   
12          volkswagen model 111  27.0          4           97          60    1834        19.0    71  European
```